# Finding the solution of cosx and sinx via Operator Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ (D^2 + 1)y = x + 2\cos x + \sin x$$
I could'nt apply the operator $D$ due to nominator is $0$..

Comment: What? Is not the equation $y''+y=x+2\cos x+\sin x?$

Comment: Yes but it is required to solve by using the operator method D. If not, yes ım able to solve via variation of parameters..

Comment: What is $D$?${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Operator method..I think this method only used for engineering systems. what i mean..check this sir https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHqx1qxA8q4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(D^2 + 1)y_p= 2\cos x$$
Since $e^{ix}= \cos x +i \sin x \implies \cos x = \Re e^{ix}$:
$$(D^2 + 1)y = 2\Re e^{ix}$$
$$y_p=2\Re \dfrac 1 {D^2+1}e^{ix}$$
$$y_p=2\Re e^{ix}\dfrac 1 {(D+i)^2+1}1$$
$$y_p=2\Re e^{ix}\dfrac 1 {D(D+2i)}1$$
$$y_p=2\Re \dfrac {e^{ix}}{2i}\left (\dfrac 1 D-  \dfrac 1{D+2i} \right)1$$
$$y_p=\Re \dfrac {e^{ix}}{i}\left (x-  \dfrac 1{2i} \right)$$
Since we have $e^{ix}= \cos x +i \sin x$, we take the real part and get this:
$$y_p=x \sin x +  \dfrac 1{2} \cos x$$
This gives you ( the cos function is absorbed by the homogeneous solution of the DE):
$$y_p=x \sin x$$
Do the same for :
$$(D^2 + 1)y_p = \sin x$$
$$y_p=\Im \dfrac 1 {D^2+1}e^{ix}$$
$$y_p=\Im e^{ix} \dfrac 1 {(D+i)^2+1}1$$
Where $\Im$ is the imaginary part.

Comment: when I see masters like you..Im happy to live in this world..maths is the unique in everywhere...thanks really sir..

Comment: You're very welcome @cittacitaa